# Input impedances in CB and CE transistor circuits

Tags: transistors, diodes, pn-junction

Considering the input signal being placed across the Emitter-Base junction directly in both circuits(Common base and Common emitter), and considering this junction similar to a normal forward biased diode, doesn’t that imply, according to Shockley’s equation, that the current in the diode should be the same regardless of any connection? Trying this circuit on Proteus gives me different results though:

[image]

So why is this different in the case of a transistor than a normal pn- junction?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 its just for testing

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 regardless of the circuit in the picture, I am asking why is the input impedance different though the EB junction still has the same conductivity whatever you do in the outer circuit as long as the potential difference across this junction stays the same. Similarly, why is the output impedance different in Common emitter than in common collector though the current will have to pass through all three regions in both ways and they’re both forward biased?

Comment: CB, CE and CC may require you have some resistance in series with terminal that is being regulated by another with a shared common. Here you have ideal voltage sources across every junction

Comment: any questions?.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 thank you so much for your efforts, I am still trying to wrap up everything and if I still have more questions I’ll add them

Comment: How did you understand my simulation?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 it is pretty good and simple as I’m trying to grasp the theory of transistors for the first time, thank you!

Comment: You will notice on the right side if you raise the Vc2 above the PNP base to a forward bias condition , the simulation blows up with gigaamps which is what would happen in an ideal terawatt diode as Vbc becomes forward biased. as a diode and is well beyond saturation.  (chuckles at javascript blowing up). Although Falstad included a few standard diodes , the Logic and Op Amps have ideal voltage source drivers and ideal RLC parts so to make them really one adds ESR or DCR or ESL.  But don't worry about this yet, most students don't learn that till later.

Comment: CE is bad polarized i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ehm... Proteus forgot to tell you your Transistor is blown with Vbe-5V but it did try to limit the current by some bulk resistance for Vbe and Vce.

Both of these circuits are neither CB, common base nor CE, common emitter.

WHY? because you have no current limiting resistors and logically the ground symbol is just an arbitrary convenient way to define 0 Vdc and not "earth gnd". But Proteus may have assumed the bulk resistance for saturation of Vbe and Vce for your device and displayed that current. (IDK) I don't know... It's a Proteus error exceeding device Vbe ratings by orders of magnitude.

You could have in fact chosen any terminal as 0V but that does not make it CB, CE or CC, until you add resistors to modulate the voltage or current to achieve some voltage and/or current gain with a common terminal, shared between input and output.

The gnd. symbol only means an arbitrary 0V Reference.

[Here is Falstad's simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMjoA4BsB2ATNzjs4BOVA9EAFgGYRsQ4I4BTAWmQChEclNyu%20KFHuQiZwlSEIjTICAGoAjROwDuIKtgiIidDRE2okq9ZqToIepASNqDw2t35GALg7pPLTiGxBFIRAMCA1CJ0IkxDFjBIUgJSdER0CkQ4ZCJEJBgQABMmADMAQwBXABtndgAlEy1rS1RpcQpGcRk4Tm5LbCbqt3ExNm8EAZbZEDkAY2UuOjhzWm7Z-W5REGG6Ydax8exK%20jnkGbn6lsoGs9l2V1T3Xj2tW%208MoejYsEJUKjBUr9TDRCzcoVSuU1BRjk5rvZlGpFkhsIZYQcbHckDoUV0tO06GD7uRBH8HiB%20s9IOQWAhNoodgAPdQRWhEejwkyUJBCAAWADEAKIAHQAzvymM4Bc4APYC-5gAUACjyAEtqUxsgBKdgAJyhtzsXkyYA1KMSjH2zMxtM%20hg0umw5A0CCEiCEAGFuexaXAKLbEAj0AgNBkHc6nQbOmBLaYMeJlAAHQ1zJJafYtdix0OGQjkHXJ2kpfSZ7CMguswwAFUgAoAys4mCoCuqRfyAILR9UCzTYZRAA) of the Shockley Equation and it will blow up with GigaAmps because it is not device-specific, so I added the necessary resistors to conform to the model for CB and CC.

You simply choose hFE but in more advanced details you may choose a dozen unique device parameters for diodes but these are not needed if you add the bulk resistance e.g. Rce=Vce(sat)/Ic(sat), but as a current sink/source ,this is never needed.

I spent a few minutes adding some sliders for the ideal voltage sources and added resistors. The voltage varies from a range of Vbe 0.6V to your 5V.

[image]

Comment: If you reduce the resistors to 1m , the simulation may need a reset and undo ^-Z if you want to revert... Going back to painting upstairs

Answer (score 0):

In the CB arrangement the current from the collector also has to come from the input in addition to that flowing through the base.

Since the base current is multiplied by the gain of the transistor it means that for an incremental change in input voltage there is much more current change in CB than CE.

As a result the input impedance is much lower.